# wxPython: Drawing inside a ScrolledPanel

Tags: python, wxpython, scroll

I'm using a PaintDC to draw inside a ScrolledPanel. However, when I run the program, the scroll bars have no effect. They're the right size, but the picture doesn't move when you scroll with them.

I figured I may have to convert from logical to device coordinates. I tried `x=dc.LogicalToDeviceX(x)` and `y=dc.LogicalToDeviceY(y)`, but there was no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
(new_x,new_y)=self.CalcScrolledPosition((old_x,old_y))
```

Where `self` is the ScrolledPanel.